# Libcurl via threads

Tags: c#, libcurl

I am coding program on c# (C#, & object oriented programming newbie) 
I am trying to download pages in multiple threads. There are no problems when running only 1 thread. Problems starts when I run multiple.

It seems like all of the threads save the downloaded info in the same variable SockBuff, but I have no ideas what to do to solve this problem.

Suggestions ?

Here is the code

Program starts when I click button.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void TestaThread_1()
        {
            Random RandomNumber = new Random();
            int rand = RandomNumber.Next(99);

            HTTP cURL = new HTTP();
            cURL.CurlInit();
            String data = cURL.HTTPGet("http://google.com", "", "fails" + rand.ToString() + ".html");
            HTTP.save_file("fails" + rand.ToString()+ ".html", data);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TestaThread_1));
            thread1.Start();

            Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TestaThread_1));
            thread2.Start();

            Thread thread3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TestaThread_1));
            thread3.Start();

            Thread thread4 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TestaThread_1));
            thread4.Start();

            Thread thread5 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TestaThread_1));
            thread5.Start();
        }
    }

    class HTTP
    {
        public Easy easy;        
        public static string SockBuff;
        public string CookieFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "cookie.txt";
        public string UserAgent = "Mozilla 5.0";
        public string Proxy = "";


        public void CurlInit()
        {
            Curl.GlobalInit((int)CURLinitFlag.CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
        }


        public string HTTPGet(string URL, string Proxy, String FailaNosaukums)
        {
            easy = new Easy();
            SockBuff = "";

            try
            {
                Easy.WriteFunction wf = new Easy.WriteFunction(OnWriteData);

                easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_URL, URL);
                easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, "60");
                easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, wf);
                easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_USERAGENT, UserAgent);
                easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, CookieFile);
                easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, CookieFile);
                easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

                if (URL.Contains("https"))
                {
                    easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
                    easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                }

                if (Proxy != "")
                {
                    easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_PROXY, Proxy);
                    easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLproxyType.CURLPROXY_HTTP);
                }

                easy.Perform();
                easy.Cleanup();

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Get Request Error");
            }

            return SockBuff;
        }


        public static Int32 OnWriteData(Byte[] buf, Int32 size, Int32 nmemb, Object extraData)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int RandomNumber = rand.Next(1000);

            SockBuff = SockBuff + System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);

            return size * nmemb;
        }

        static public void save_file(string file_name, string text_to_write)
        {
            StreamWriter MyStream = null;
            string MyString = text_to_write;

            try
            {
                MyStream = File.CreateText(file_name);
                MyStream.Write(MyString);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (MyStream != null)
                    MyStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I got another question.

Why can't I save image files using save_file function correctly? Are there encoding problems in the buff ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `SockBuff` is `static`, so there's only one instance of that variable that's shared by all instances of the `HTTP` class.  You can probably solve the problem by removing the `static`.

If you do that, you'll also have to make your `OnWriteData` method an instance method (i.e. not static).

You might also consider looking into using `System.Net.WebClient` and/or `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` classes instead of Libcurl.

Comment: Worked good! Thanks. Why is the System.Net better than the libcurl?

Comment: I'm happy my answer was helpful.  It's not that the System.Net classes are 'better' than Libcurl.  Honestly, I don't know enough about Libcurl on .NET to say which is better.  But in my experience it makes sense to use the .NET libraries when possible because it simplifies things (don't have to include other libraries), they typically work well, and they will be more widely used and understood (meaning that I can more easily get help on them if I need it).

Comment: @user444434 Can you please share how you solved the above with threads?

Comment: @user44434: The solution was to make SockBuff an instance varible so that each thread gets its own buffer.